# SQL: multi-part identifier "c.name" could not be bound

Tags: sql

I am modifying a script from mssqltips.com that generates a script to recreate all indexes in a database. I am enclosing it in a TRY and the CATCH will call a stored proc and passes it 5 arguments. One of them, c.name is intended to be the primary key of the parent table, but throws the "The multi-part identifier "c.name" could not be bound." error. Sorry for the longevity of the code but thought it migh be relevant to see all of it.
[image]

I posted an image since the SQL was quite large and thought the syntax highlighting would be helpful. Here is where I am at now.

```
SELECT @create += N'BEGIN TRY ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(cs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ct.name) + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + ' FOREIGN KEY (' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
FROM sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')  + ') REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME(rs.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(rt.name)  + '(' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(sc.name)
FROM sys.columns AS sc 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc ON fkc.referenced_column_id = sc.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = sc.[object_id]
WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id 
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'') + '); END TRY BEGIN CATCH EXEC pr_purged_orphaned ' 
    +  QUOTENAME(ct.name) + ' , ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name) + ' , ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' , ' + QUOTENAME(rt.name) + ' , ''_cID_project_''' FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS rt ON fk.referenced_object_id = rt.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS rs ON rt.[schema_id] = rs.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS ct ON fk.parent_object_id = ct.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS cs ON ct.[schema_id] = cs.[schema_id]  WHERE rt.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND ct.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

Comment: You should post your actual query, not just an image of it.  However, your last reference to `quotename(c.name)` doesn't include `sys_columns` in its `from` clause...

Comment: Posting an *image* (screenshot) of a SQL statement is pretty close to useless.

Answer (score 0):

There is no object with 'c' as alias in your inline query. That is the reason for getting this error.If you wanted to get the column name, then use 'sc.name' instead of 'c.name'.

Comment: I actually tried that already with the same result. What is weird is I can reference rt.name, ct.name & fk.name without an issue.

Comment: can you place your actual code instead of the image?

Answer (score 0):

But as others have indicated, I do not have a c alias in my inline query. Once I formatted the code I could see that. Joining sys.columns to sys.tables will fix the issue.